# Holomorphic curve

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, curves

Consider the holomorphic curve
$$
\Gamma:=\left\{(z, w) \in \mathbb{C}^{2}: z^{2}=w^{3}\right\}
$$

My question is how can I imagine this? I studied that a holomorphic curve in $\mathbb{C}^n$ is a holomorphic map from an open set of the complex number to $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ for some $n$. If it were a real curve I would have no difficulties in parametrizing it with a parameter $t$ and seeing that the form it takes is the curve $y=x^{\frac{2}{3}}$, which is a cusp with a singularity in the origin. My question is how can I imagine the following curve in the complex numbers? How can I prove it has a singularity in the origin? Thanks!

Comment: You can still parametrize by $t \mapsto (z,w) = (t^3,t^2)$; does that help?

Comment: Do you mean, in case, $t \mapsto (z,w)=(t^2,t^3)$? So, we can basically think of it as a complex cusp?

Comment: Yes, the curve is a complex cusp, but the exponents in my comment are correct: $z^2=w^3$. :)

Comment: I see, I can pick $t \in \mathbb{C}$ and put $t=w$, so that $t \mapsto (z,w) = (t^{\frac{3}{2}}, t) = (t^3,t^2)$. Thanks @Andrew

Comment: If it matters, power functions with non-integer exponent over the complex numbers require subtle care with domain issues, so it's safest to view the $(t^{3/2}, t)$ pathway only formally, as motivation.